# Conditional Validation in PDF

Tags: javascript, validation, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am looking to create a form where a text field is required based on a yes/no question in a previous field. I can structure the yes/no question as either a Dropdown List or as Radio Buttons. I am not using a "Submit" button or any other button on the form (and would prefer not to), but would like the person to receive an error message if they try to save the PDF and the conditional field is not filled in.

I have tried several different solutions from my research online, but have not gotten anything to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A generic form validation uses a list of field names to check.

Then you loop through the list and compare the field's value with its defaultValue; if the same, the field is not filled, and you should mark this.

Even if you don't submit, you can use the required property. Instead of a list with field names, you would loop through all fields and test whether the required property is set, and then, if so, test for the field's value, as above.

To make it more user friendly, you might assemble an alert message, or change a visual property of the field which is not filled. Just don't forget to reset that property when the field gets filled.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the user from saving the PDF in Adobe Acrobat.

You can use the JavaScript hook for "document will save" (see the list of document events [here|https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/entering-document-actions]) and execute some JavaScript code as part of this hook to alert the user that they still need to fill in a field if the field has not been filled in.

To get to the "Document Actions" view in Acrobat DC, open the "JavaScript" tool and select "Document Actions". It should look something like this[image: Screenshot of Document Actions view of JavaScript tool in Adobe Acrobat DC]

Comment: I believe this would be fine. I'm not looking to prevent people from saving, I just would like an alert message to pop up when they do save saying that they need to fill out fied X (then whether they do or not is their choice). Can someone help me with the code by chance? I'm pretty new to JavaScript and can usually edit existing code, but am not at a level where I can write my own. (Not sure if this is out of the scope for this forum.)